# Не работает bash скрипт

Tags: bash

Написал простенький bash скрипт `.bashrc`

```
foot()
{
    echo "Hello World22222!"
}
export -f foot
```

Набираю `bash .bashrc`
Потом `foot` и ничего не выводится. Почему? Хотя один раз сработало, с названием функции `foo`. Теперь у меня в консоле по `foo` выводиться "Hello World". Как удалить это `foo` и заставить работать баш скрипт, который выше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете `bash .bashrc` - запускается новый экземпляр bash, там скрипт отрабатывает корректно. Затем этот экземпляр bash благополучно завершается. На тот шелл, в котором вы работаете - изменений не оказывается.

Поскольку речь, судя по всему, о `~/.bashrc`, то вам необходимо после его изменений разлогиниться и залогиниться вновь (можно запустить другую консоль) - тогда изменение будет видно.

Либо, что удобнее для отладки, вызывать вот так: `. .bashrc`. На примере:

```
melkij@melkij:~/tmp$ foot
bash: foot: команда не найдена
melkij@melkij:~/tmp$ cat rc
#!/bin/bash
foot()
{
    echo "Hello World22222!"
}
export -f foot
melkij@melkij:~/tmp$ . rc
melkij@melkij:~/tmp$ foot
Hello World22222!
melkij@melkij:~/tmp$
```

Как видно, такой вызов исполняется в рамках текущего процесса.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так - `source .bashrc`